# Can't drag IBAction from UITapGestureRecognizer in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ibaction, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to drag an IBAction from my UITapGestureRecognizer, which was placed on an UIImageView that resides in a custom tableview cell.

However, it does not allow me to drag an action from storyboard to the custom tableview cell's subclass

The cell's class is properly set to the correct file in the identity inspector. And user interaction is enabled on the imageview.

So I tried typing out the IBAction and connecting it from the file to storyboard, and it gives this error:

[image: Error after connecting IBAction]

This is perplexing because I am able to drag IBActions from UIButtons and other view objects; just not this UITapGestureRecognizer. I have recently updated Xcode to 7.2.1

Here's my view hierarchy from the document outline:

[image: Custom cell document outline]

Here's the tap gesture's connections:

[image: imageview's connections]

And the imageview's connections:

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. You're trying to connect an IBAction from UITableViewCell to UIViewController or UIViewController subclass.You can add it your UITableView and then use locationInView and indexPathForRowAtPoint to determine which row was tapped.

Comment: @beyowulf I am not aware of any view controller being involved with what i am doing here. I am attempting to connect the gesture to my cell class (which is repeatable); not a view controller.

Comment: My bad, you used to be able to do what you're doing, but iOS 9 only change how UIGestureRecognizers can be used with UITableViews and UICollectionViews. I edited my comment.

Comment: @beyowulf Oh, I was not aware of that change (knowing that I could do this in the past made this especially confusing). Thanks for the heads up; I will just do it programmatically then.

Answer (score 5):

I always added tap gesture recognizer object in code instead of working on Storyboard, now after many Xcode versions changes (currently 8.1, swift 3.0). I revisited some similar issue when trying to work with Tap Gesture Regnizer on Story board. I landed on this page even though I am working on a simple UIImageView with added Tap Gesture Recognizer object (drag and drop Tap Gesture Recognizer object into your image view). Here I listed a small step by step tutorial and hope it's useful to others who ended up on this page like me.

1) Make sure your image view has these connections in the inspector before continue

[image]

2) Added @IBAction response function in you swift code.

```
 // MARK: Actions
  @IBAction func tapGestureAction (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("Tap on Flower Image View")
  }
```

3) On Main.storyboard, click on the Tap Gesture object either from 'Document outline' or the icons collection in your view controller scene.
[image]

or

[image]

4) Go to Connections Inspector and ctrl + click the plus sign next to 'selector' in 'Sent Actions' and drag it to view controller icon of the scene. Once release the mouse you will see the name of your function defined in step 2) show up. You can select and that should make the connection.

[image]

[image]

5) If the connection successfully made, the Connections Inspector of Tap Gesture Recognizer object should look like below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As beyowulf points out in the comments above, there was a change in iOS 9 that changed how UIGestureRecognizers work with repeating content.

This is unfortunate because I find it best practice to use storyboards over programmatic implementation, but if you're trying to figure this out here's the code:

In your custom cell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let imageViewDoubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
         target: self,
         action:#selector(ThisClass.userSwiped)
         )
    imageViewDoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.photoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageViewDoubleTap)
}
```

Then create a func with the same name you provided the action parameter and implement your code in there.

Comment: Astounding, thanks for that!  edited to latest selector syntax